# snmp value range constraint not implemented while doing snmp walk

Tags: integer, snmp, rfc, pysnmp

I had performed SNMP walk for Host Resources MIB.

For more understanding of Host Resource MIB please refer this

https://www.netscantools.com/snmp-host-resources-mib-analysis.html

The snmp walk is done using command

`snmpwalk -v 2c -c <community_string> <ip_address>  1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3`

Here value of hrStorageRam

`HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageType.1 = OID: HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES::hrStorageRam`

gave size value

`HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.1 = INTEGER: 2677943624`
with allocation unit of 1024 Bytes

While going through RFC page for this MIB https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2790

We can see that hrStorageType is Intger32 type and has constraint of range -2147483648 to 2147483647

But why is SNMP walk giving result more than this constraint.

Wanted to verify if SNMP walk follows this RFC2790 rule or not.

Comment: `snmpwalk` probably don't bother to verify the value returned by SNMP agents. Anyway, the "incorrect" result was given by the SNMP agent you tested against, not `snmpwalk` itself.

Comment: @LexLi  is not snmp walk supported by netsnmp and
when i went through there documentation there is constraint value for Integer32 as mentioned in RFC 
i am having constraint value error in pysnmp due to this reason and am not very sure how to proceed further 
The issue is similar to this https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjLiZbn_8TtAhVhmeYKHbOaASwQFjABegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fetingof%2Fpysnmp%2Fissues%2F357&usg=AOvVaw3QcoK6vhFvxzJs6ITlcvb3
do you have any comment on this

Comment: You are the one who should decide to validate the value or not. If you do want to validate that, then what you must do is more than merely an SNMP WALK operation (which is a bunch of GET NEXT or GET BULK operations), but also require a MIB document parser to load all necessary documents and extract the constraints. That's why `pysnmp` reports errors (as it validates) and some other tools don't.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that it depends which SNMPWALK and which version you use.
There are bugs all over the place.

First, the agent is supposed to return the correct value. So if it does not, that's a bug.

But, even if it does not, because in SNMP the devices are supposed to be the
"simple" ones, the management application is supposed to be the "smart"
one, and handle it correctly.

Anyway, I took 5 minutes to test this with MIMIC Simulator and NET-SNMP version

```
% snmpwalk -V
NET-SNMP version: 5.8
```

and it behaves correctly (eg. with your exact value):

```
% snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.0.0.8 .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.5
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.1 = INTEGER: 0
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.2 = INTEGER: 1150404
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.3 = INTEGER: -1617023672
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.4 = INTEGER: 7483
```